# Question about Hatcher Proposition 3.33 dealing with directed limits

Tags: algebraic-topology

We have a space $X$ which is the union of a collection of subspaces $X_\alpha$ forming a directed set with order relation inclusion. Then for fixed $i$ and $G$ the homology groups $H_{i}(X_\alpha;G)$ form a directed system, using the homomorphisms induced by inclusion.

> He then says the natural maps $H_i(X\alpha;G) \rightarrow H_i(X;G)$, induced by inclusion $X_\alpha \rightarrow X$, induce a homomorphism $\lim_{\rightarrow}H_i(X_\alpha;G) \rightarrow H_i(X;G)$.
>
> It is not clear to me how to define this induced map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induced maps $f_i:H_i(X_\alpha;G)\rightarrow H_i(X;G)$ are induced by the inclusions $\iota_i:X_i\hookrightarrow X$, so $f_i=(\iota_i)_\ast$. We also have inclusion maps $\tau_\alpha: X_\alpha\hookrightarrow X_{\alpha+1}$ which induce maps $g_i:H_i(X_\alpha;G)\rightarrow(X_{\alpha+1};G)$. As the diagram consisting of $X$ the $X_\alpha$ with the $\iota_\alpha$ and $\tau_\alpha$ as maps is commutative also the diagram consisting of $H_i(X;G)$, the $H_i(X_\alpha)$, the $f_\alpha$ and the $g_\alpha$ is commutative ($H_i$ is a functor). But now the universal property of the colimit gives us a map $\varinjlim H_i(X_\alpha;G)\rightarrow H_i(X;G)$. This is the map Hatcher is talking about.